# Preserve whitelines between paragraphes in pandoc md to tex conversion

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I am unable to get paragraphs preserved when using `pandoc` to render `.tex` from `.md`. The text gets clutched together and no `\newline`, `\bigskip` or whatever gets added to the `.tex` output.

Since this is a pretty basic task and I am trying to achieve this basic functionality for way too long now, I am guessing that I encountered a bug.

I use `--wrap preserve`. It is documented to preserve *no semantic linebreaks*, but I'm unsure whether this preserves whitelines between paragraphs.

What I want:

```
Lorem ipsum para one.

Lorem ipsum para two.
```

What I get

```
Lorem ipsum para one.
Lorem ipsum para two.
```

I use the followoing template (mostly generated by `latexila`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{$title$}
\author{$author$}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


$body$

\end{document}
```

Newline control works with two whitespaces on the end of a line, but the empty whitelines are not preserved.

I tried writing a python filter. My pandoc (2.5) on Ubuntu 19.10 is still using python 2.7 and I am unable to make it use python 3. It's plainly ignoring what I write into the shebang.
I am unwilling to code python 2 in 2020.

Any ideas what may go wrong here? How could one enforce python3 usage for pandoc filters?

Comment: It's not clear to me, wether you want whitespace between paragraphs (that would be a matter of `\parskip`) or line breaks within paragraphs.

Comment: @DG' Thanks for your reply, I updated the question.

Comment: Which version of pandoc are you using? Did you change the template?

Comment: @DG' I am working with pandoc 2.5 on Ubuntu 19.10. I changed the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the distance between paragraphs with `\parskip` and the indentation of the first line with `\parindent`. Pandoc's default template sets it to:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
```

If you are using a custom template, you have to add those settings as well.

---

Two spaces (or more) at the end of a line will give you a hard break.

From the manual:

> **Paragraphs**
>
> A paragraph is one or more lines of text followed by one or more blank lines. Newlines 
>   are treated as spaces, so you can reflow your paragraphs as you like. If you need a hard 
>   line break, put two or more spaces at the end of a line.

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   
consetetur sadipscing elitr,  
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  
sed diam voluptua.  
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos e accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. t
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I started with. I read the friendly manual. Ending the prepending line with spaces or inserting lines with only two or more spaces does end in paragraphes clutched together. I want to achieve what you achieved before `Duis` and `Ut` in your example.

Comment: In that case, you should look into you pandoc template and change the value for `\parskip` and `\parindent`. I used the default template for this example, which uses `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and   `\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}`

Comment: No `\parindent` or `\parskip` statements are getting added during conversion from `md` to `tex`. Are these commands implicit, when I leave a blank line? Otherwise it would make no sense to me to redefine elements not used...?

Comment: Latex default is to have no space between paragraphs, but to indent the first line. If you want to have whitespace and no indentation, you have to explicitly set the lengths.

Comment: OK, finally. Learned a lesson about latex magic. Adding the two `\setlength` definitions to my template made it work. Thanks a lot.